# valor de input com 'find' não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, array

Tenho uma lista que incrementada dinamicamente com o append do jquery, a lista é mais ou menos assim:

```
    $("#questoes").append(
        '<li class="questao" data-id="'+questao+'">'+
            '<div class="row testes">'+
                '<div class="left-col col col-md-11">'+
                '<input type="number" class="form-input questao_numero" style="max-width: 160px" placeholder="Nº da questão" data-chave="numero_questao">' +
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="right-col col-6 col-md-1">'+
                '<i data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-'+questao+'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-'+questao+'" class="questoes_arrow fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' +
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div id="collapse-'+questao+'" class="collapse questoes_arrow_container show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-'+questao+'">' +
            '<div class="questao-body">' +
            '<h4 class="h5">Enunciado da questão: </h4>' +
                '<textarea name="enunciado" class="form-control questao_enunciado" data-chave="questao_enunciado">Enunciado da questão</textarea>' +
                '<div class="line"></div>' +
                '<h4 class="h5">Alternativas da questão: </h4>' +
                '<ul class="alternativas"></ul>'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm nova_alternativa">+ Add nova alternativa</button>' +
                '<div class="line"></div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</li>'
);
```

Estou usando o seguinte código para percorrer os elementos da lista e pegar o valor dos inputs contidos em cada item da lista e colocar em um array:

```
    $("#salvar_alteracoes").click(function(){

    var questoes = new Array();
    $("#questoes").each(function(i, e){
        $(this).find('li').each(function (j) {
            var questao = {
                "questao_numero" : $(this).find('.questao_numero').val(),
                "questao_enunciado" : $(this).find('.questao_enunciado').val(),
            };

            questoes.push(questao);
        });
    });
});
```

Mas usando "$(this).find('.questao_numero').val()" não está pegando o valor do input porque?

Comment: porque está `<ul class="questoes">` para que funcione `<ul class="questoes" id="questoes">`

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza No código original está com id, é que ao passar aqui eu acabei colocando errado. E não funciona mesmo assim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código possui um problema: não existem as class `.questao_numero` e `.questao_enunciado`. Ou você coloca as referidas `class` nos respectivos elementos ou pegue os valores pelo nome da tag, já que só existem essas duas, `input` e `textarea` (coloquei um `value="123"` no `input` apenas para exemplificar):

```js
questao = 1;
$("#questoes").append(
  '<li class="questao" data-id="'+questao+'">'+
      '<div class="row testes">'+
          '<div class="left-col col col-md-11">'+
          '<input value="123" type="number" class="form-input numero_questao" style="max-width: 160px" placeholder="Nº da questão" data-chave="numero_questao">' +
          '</div>'+
          '<div class="right-col col-6 col-md-1">'+
          '<i data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-'+questao+'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-'+questao+'" class="questoes_arrow fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' +
          '</div>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div id="collapse-'+questao+'" class="collapse questoes_arrow_container show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-'+questao+'">' +
      '<div class="questao-body">' +
      '<h4 class="h5">Enunciado da questão: </h4>' +
          '<textarea name="enunciado" class="form-control enunciado_questao" data-chave="enunciado_questao">Enunciado da questão</textarea>' +
          '<div class="line"></div>' +
          '<h4 class="h5">Alternativas da questão: </h4>' +
          '<ul class="alternativas"></ul>'+
          '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm nova_alternativa">+ Add nova alternativa</button>' +
          '<div class="line"></div>' +
      '</div>' +
  '</li>'
);

var questoes = new Array();
$("#questoes").each(function(i, e){
    $(this).find('li').each(function (j) {
        var questao = {
            "questao_numero" : $(this).find('input').val(),
            "questao_enunciado" : $(this).find('textarea').val(),
        };
        questoes.push(questao);
        console.log(questoes); // para mostrar os valores
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="questoes">
</ul>
```

Comment: é que eu copiei um trecho antigo, me desculpe.

Comment: e sobre isso: id="'+questao+'" , é porque a lista é incrementada com o append do jquery e esse trecho estava dentro do append

Comment: @LeandroSilvaCampos Entendi, e já atualizei a resposta de acordo com a pergunta.

Comment: funcionou, mas eu precisava que ele selecionasse através da classe ou outro seletor especifico, pois dentro de cada item da lista das questões terão também inputs referentes as alternativas e fazendo assim ele vai pegar o valor das alternativas também e adicionar no indice "numero_questao". Não tem como fazer por um seletor em especifico?

Comment: @LeandroSilvaCampos Dentro de cada <li> terá mais de 1 input?

Comment: @LeandroSilvaCampos Vc vai colocar 1 classe diferente pra cada input?

Comment: já descobri o erro, o nome das classes realmente estavam errados. eu estava usando o find('questao_numero') e a classe está com nome 'numero_questao' kkkk perdi bom tempo com isso e não vi essa burrice minha. Mas vou marcar sua reposta como correta porque no fim das era esse o problema

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você esta tentando acessar um elemento por um seletor que não foi  definido, veja:

1. Você esta tentando acessar como `.numero_questao` sendo que você não atribuiu esse valor ao campo, pelo contrário você apenas colocou como `.num_quest`

   ```
   <input type="number" name="numero_questao" class="form-input num_quest" style="max-width: 160px" placeholder="Nº da questão" data-chave="numero_questao" value="225">
   ```
2. Você esta tentando acessar como `.questao_enunciado` sendo que você não atribuiu esse valor ao campo, pelo contrário você apenas colocou como `.enunciado`

   ```
   <textarea name="enunciado" class="form-control enunciado" data-chave="enunciado">Enunciado da questão</textarea>
   ```

Agora se o que você quer é acessar o elemento pelo atributo `data-chave` você deve fazer a seguintes alterações:

```
var questao = {
    "questao_numero" : $(this).find('[data-chave="numero_questao"]').val(),
    "questao_enunciado" : $(this).find('[data-chave="enunciado"]').val(),
};
```

Veja funcionando:

```js
var questoes = new Array();
$("#questoes").each(function(i, e){
    $(this).find('li').each(function (j) {
        var questao = {
            "questao_numero" : $(this).find('[data-chave="numero_questao"]').val(),
            "questao_enunciado" : $(this).find('[data-chave="enunciado"]').val(),
        };

        questoes.push(questao);
    });
});

console.log(questoes);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<ul id="questoes">
    <li class="questao" id="'+questao+'">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left-col col col-md-11">
                <!-- coloquei um valor no atributo value apenas para exemplo -->
                <input type="number" name="numero_questao" class="form-input num_quest" style="max-width: 160px" placeholder="Nº da questão" data-chave="numero_questao" value="225"> 
            </div>
            <div class="right-col col-6 col-md-1">
                <i data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-'+questao+'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-questao" class="questoes_arrow fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-'+questao+'" class="collapse questoes_arrow_container show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-questao"> 
            <div class="questao-body" id="questao"> 
                <h4 class="h5">Enunciado da questão: </h4> 
                <textarea name="enunciado" class="form-control enunciado" data-chave="enunciado">Enunciado da questão</textarea> 
                <div class="line"></div> 
            </div> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado e me desculpem a burrice mas na verdade o código está correto, eu copiei um trecho antigo do código e por isso está diferente. Eu editei o post lá em cima, está tudo conforme deve ser e mesmo assim não pega o valor

Comment: quando você esta executando o código para pegar os valores ? Quando clica em algum botão ? Seria melhor colocar mais detalhes de como funciona seu código.

Comment: editei o post de novo.